# How to iterate over non zero values in a sparse matrix with COLT?

Tags: java, matrix, sparse-matrix, colt

The code example on the [COLT website](https://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/api/cern/colt/matrix/package-summary.html#Overview) shows:

```
DoubleFactory2D factory;
factory = DoubleFactory2D.sparse;

DoubleMatrix2D matrix = factory.make(3,4);
    for (int row = matrix.rows(); --row >= 0;) {
     for (int column = matrix.columns(); --column >= 0;) {
       value = matrix.getQuick(row, column);
     }
    }
```

but this does not take advantage of the sparsity of the matrix. I'd like to iterate over non zero values only.

Comment: If anybody reads this, I finally switched to an array of sparsevectors, because this data structure in Colt has a `getIndex()` method which returns the non zero elements of the vector.